# Looking for a short story about stopping hurricanes with nuclear weapons

Tags: story-identification

Years and years ago I read a short story that described a remote, barely-habitable planet that suffered from nearly constant hurricanes across an almost planet-wide ocean. The premise is that researchers have a colony there, and are testing ways to stop hurricanes in their tracks; this includes detonating a nuclear device in the eye of the storm. Who wrote this and what is it called?

Any chance I could also get a list of collections it had appeared in? I'm trying to track down several other stories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Year's Best SF Cover] [image: Analog Cover]

Could be "**[Eyewall](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47809)**" by Rick Shelley.

Here's an overview:

> A category 5 hurricane leaves 20,000 dead in Florida and a million
> homeless. A hurricane study group must bow to political pressure.
> Instead of pure science research, they are supposed to conduct
> experiments using explosives (including nuclear) to disrupt the eye of
> a hurricane to get it to dissipate.

This section from another review has some of the plot points you've mentioned:

> They travel to Trident, a water covered world where hurricanes are not
> only a daily occurrence but they also reach size and power unheard of.

The story has appeared in many [publications](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47809) (click the link for a list) including "The Year’s Best Science Fiction: Ninth Annual Collection" and "Analog Science Fiction and Fact: January 1991" (covers posted above). Read a preview [here](http://tinyurl.com/p7dzymm).

*~ Reviews edited from [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/The-Years-Best-Science-Fiction/product-reviews/0312078900) and [Rat’s Reading Blog](http://reading.kingrat.biz/reviews/years-best-science-fiction-nine-gardner-dozois)*

Comment: That's definitely it. I had a copy of the ninth annual year's best collection and the rest of the stories in the list match up with what I was looking for. Thanks!